# Worklight: WL.Server.setActiveUser - Can't modify - Illegal State: Cannot change identity

Tags: session, ibm-mobilefirst, adapter

I am trying to modify the logged in user identity,

```
var mydata="this is custom data array";

var user = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(WL.Server.getActiveUser()));
           WL.Logger.debug("Before Update" + user.attributes);
           WL.Logger.debug(" displayName =" + user.displayName );
           WL.Logger.debug("isUserAuthenticated ="+ user.isUserAuthenticated );
           WL.Logger.debug("userId =" + user.userId );

          WL.Server.setActiveUser ("myAppRealm" ,{    userId: user.userId ,
               displayName: user.displayName,
               isUserAuthenticated: user.isUserAuthenticated,
               attributes: {  userdata: mydata   }
           } );
           WL.Logger.debug(" ---- Updateed user ---- "  );
           var user = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(WL.Server.getActiveUser()));
```

but its **giving below exception**.

```
response [/apps/services/api/myApp/common/query] success: /*-secure-
{"isSuccessful":false,"warnings":[],"errors":["Illegal State: Cannot change identity of an already logged in user in realm 'myAppRealm'. The application must logout first."],"responseID":"67","info":[]}*/ worklight.js:1097
Procedure invocation error. Illegal State: Cannot change identity of an already logged in user in realm 'myAppRealm'. The application must logout first.
```

How can I modify this?

**Edit:**

@Xv. Well, that time I had requirement to save some values in a user's  session object. For that I first tried modifying user's object as mentioned above but then I found below mentioned APIs that helps in retrieving , modifying or adding values in a session object.

**WL 6.3 docs:**

- [MobileFirst server-side API>JavaScript server-side API>Classes>WL.Server](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-server/html/WL.Server.html?cp=SSHS8R_6.3.0%2F9-1-0-1-6)

> Accessing an HttpServletRequest object.
>
> - WL.Server.getClientRequest

This gives you direct access to **HttpServletRequest** object and then you can use all of its methods as you would do in JEE applications.

*For example:*

> WL.Server.getClientRequest().getSession().getAttribute("mykey") 
>   WL.Server.getClientRequest().getSession().setAttribute("mykey", myobj)

Comment: It would be great if you could add an answer with the workaround you describe in a comment to Anton's answer: it would allow upovoting it and make linking easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Always** supply a **realm** name in `getActiveUser` API, e.g. `WL.Server.getActiveUser("myRealm")`
2. Just like error message says - you cannot alter active user identity, it is **not** mutable. What you need to do is to dispose of existing user identity first by invoking `WL.Server.setActiveUser("myRealm", null)` and then call `WL.Server.setActiveUser("myRealm", {...})`

Comment: Yes i first call WL.Server.getActiveUser("myRealm") and then i WL.Server.setActiveUser. But i have not tried first disposing/removing existing user identity and then setting it again. But i have found another work around , that looks good to me, it is directly saving in the HTTPSession using this syntax. ( **var obj= WL.Server.getClientRequest ().getSession().getAttribute("mykey")**   and   **WL.Server.getClientRequest().getSession().setAttribute("mykey", myobj)** ) have declared it inside Adapters . Thanks

Comment: @AAhad, please either accept this answer, or write your own answer and accept that.