# Worklight logout does not clear active user

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server

I am using Worklight 6.1 and am using a challange handler to determine if my user is logged or not.

Once logged in, I have the following code attached to my logout button in my app:

```
on(logoutBtn, "click", lang.hitch(this, function() {
    WL.Client.logout('AdapterAuthRealm', { onSuccess:lang.hitch(this, function() {
        this.gotoView("login");
    }), onFailure:lang.hitch(this, function() {
        WL.Logger.error("Unable to logout");
    })});
    return false;
}));
```

Clicking it opens the login view, but when the user tries to login again, the following error is shown:

```
"Cannot change identity of an already logged in user in realm 'AdapterAuthRealm'.
The application must logout first."`
```

According to the following SO question:
[Worklight: WL.Server.setActiveUser - Cann't modify - Illegal State: Cannot change identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16997804/worklight-wl-server-setactiveuser-cannt-modify-illegal-state-cannot-chang)

I will first have to clear the active user before setting a new one:

```
WL.Server.setActiveUser("AdapterAuthRealm", null);
```

I actually expected WL.Client.logout to do this automaticly, but doing so myself in my onLogout function in my adapter does not seem to have any effect:

```
<realm loginModule="NonValidatingLoginModule" name="AdapterAuthRealm">
  <className>com.worklight.integration.auth.AdapterAuthenticator</className>
  <parameter name="login-function" value="PortalAdapter.onAuthRequired"/>
  <parameter name="logout-function" value="PortalAdapter.onLogout"/>            
</realm>
```

And

```
function onLogout() {
    WL.Logger.info("invoke logout request");
    WL.Server.setActiveUser("AdapterAuthRealm", null);

    var input = {
        method : 'get',
        returnedContentType : 'text/plain',
        path : '/logoutUrl'
    };

    WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}
```

Adding it to my login function in my adapter as follows:

```
var userIdentity = { userId: username, displayName: username, attributes: {}};
WL.Server.setActiveUser("AdapterAuthRealm", null);
WL.Server.setActiveUser("AdapterAuthRealm", userIdentity);
```

Results in an infenite loop of login / logout requests of my app.

**My questions:**

1. When/where am I supposed to clear my active user?
2. When using a challange handler, is it allowed to use the WL.Client.logout method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your realm should have a logout function which should point to adapter procedure to logout. you can add this as a parameter for realm.

you can add the `WL.Server.setActiveUser("AdapterAuthRealm",null);` to the onLogout() procedure in adapter

```
<realm loginModule="loginModule" name="AdapterAuthRealm">
            <className>com.worklight.integration.auth.AdapterAuthenticator</className>
            <parameter name="login-function" value="LoginAdapter.onAuthRequired"/>
            <parameter name="logout-function" value="LoginAdapter.onLogout"/>
        </realm>
```

2 Yes. you can use WL.Client.Logout();` when using challenge handler

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this is what I was doing already, that's why I was confused in the first place...

Comment: in my case am not returning anything for onLogout()

Comment: Ah, but it does not seem to change a thing when not returning anything :-(

Comment: I couldn't paste the code properly in the comment section, so updated my original answer. Thanks for your contribution so far :-)

Comment: So the problem is resolved or still you are getting the same error?

Comment: Are you using `challengeHandler.submitSuccess();`? also onSuccess of logout try to use `WL.Client.reloadApp();` and before login check the relam is authenticated or not with `WL.Client.isUserAuthenticated("AdapterAuthRealm")`

Comment: Thanks! Adding `WL.Client.reloadApp();` in the onSuccess of the logout solved the issue!

Comment: It is because of client and server is not in sync. Please mark my answer.