# Worklight - How to check if a client is already logged in

Tags: authentication, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server, worklight-security

**LoginViewModel.js**

```
function login(){
       var username='worklight';
      var password = 'worklight';
    var invocationData = {
            adapter : "AuthenticationAdapter",
            procedure : "submitAuthentication",
            parameters : [ username, password ]
        };

        adapterAuthRealmChallengeHandler.submitAdapterAuthentication(invocationData, {});
```

**AdapterAuthRealmChallengeProcessor.js**

```
var adapterAuthRealmChallengeHandler = WL.Client.createChallengeHandler("AdapterAuthRealm");

adapterAuthRealmChallengeHandler.isCustomResponse = function(response) {
if (!response || !response.responseJSON || response.responseText === null) {
    return false;
}
if (typeof(response.responseJSON.authRequired) !== 'undefined'){
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
};

adapterAuthRealmChallengeHandler.handleChallenge = function(response){

var authRequired = response.responseJSON.authRequired;

if (authRequired == true){
    window.location = "#login";
    alert(response.responseJSON.errorMessage);

} else if (authRequired == false){
    adapterAuthRealmChallengeHandler.submitSuccess();
    window.location = "#Home";

}
};
```

**AuthenticationAdapter-impl.js**

```
function onAuthRequired(headers, errorMessage){
    errorMessage = errorMessage ? errorMessage : null;

    return {
    authRequired: true,
    errorMessage: errorMessage
    };
}

function submitAuthentication(username, password){

    var userIdentity = {
            userId: username,
            displayName: username, 
            attributes: {
                foo: "bar"
            }
    };
    WL.Server.setActiveUser("AdapterAuthRealm", userIdentity);

    return { 
        authRequired: false 
    };

}
```

I am not able to set setActiveUser. How to set it and get it. Above wat I have to done for maintaining session. Is it right way to do it. Sometimes I got error Illegal State: Cannot change identity of an already logged in user in realm 'Adapter AuthRealm'. The application must logout first. If I tried to set it null first then  it causes my application to enter an infinite loop of attempting to authenticate. Any idea why I would see this behavior?
Anything I am doing wrong?
please help mi out.

Answer (score 0):

Check the SO answer for [Worklight logout does not clear active user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23676890/worklight-logout-does-not-clear-active-user/23677525#23677525)

Try reloading app onSuccess of Logout.

```
WL.Client.logout("AdapterAuthRealm",{
                onSuccess: function(){ WL.Client.reloadApp(); },
                onFailure: function(){ WL.Logger.debug("Error on logout");}
            });
```

And you can check realm is authenticated or not by using wl client Java script API

```
WL.Client.isUserAuthenticated("AdapterAuthRealm");
```

Comment: Hey thanx for helping.. but its still not working I think variable is not getting set. Just refer my code above. I have used this on logout. But at start its not setting up.

Comment: Please share your project in Dropbox. I'll take a look into it

Comment: I have shared my code above. That's what I done. else Authenticationconfig.xml is changed. I called login function then auth adapter and set into it. and afterwards AdapterAuthRealmChallengeProcessor.js tells me true or false.

Comment: plz check it and let mi know as early as possible plz